# Why SQL query takes too long time to execute when fetching bulk data (without space)?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a problem, when getting bulk amount of data from a table.

I have a database table `TblJobs`, in this table some columns contain bulk amount of data (approx 60,000 characters in this column).

My table:

**TblJobs**

```
JobId   JobTitle     JobDescription 
----------------------------------------------------------------
 1       Job1         TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText... (approx 40,000 characters without any space in job description)  
 2       Job2         HelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHelloHell..(approx 60,000 characters without any space  in job description)  
 3       Job3         DemoDemoDemoDemoDemoDemoDemoDemoDemoDemoDemoDemo...(approx 60,000 characters without any space  in job description)  
 4       Job4         TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesti....(approx 50,000 characters without any space  in job description)
```

Structure of table is:

```
JobId          -  Int
JobTitle       -  VarChar(500)
JobDescription -  VarChar(MAX)
```

Now my problem is, when I execute query to select all columns from `TblJobs` it takes too long to execute (approx 30 sec). using this -

```
Select * from TblJobs
```

or

```
Select JobId, JobTitle, JobDescription from TblJobs
```

I was surprised when modify some data into table's column `JobDescription`, this query execute in 3-5 sec only.

In modification - I provide some spaces between data of `JobDescription` column.

For example you can see following table, in this I only include some space between `jobDescription` column (I didn't change datatype or amount of data):

```
JobId   JobTitle     JobDescription 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
 1       Job1         Text TextTextText**<space>**TextTextTextText**<space>**TextTextTextText... (approx 40,000 characters with some space in job description)  
 2       Job2         HelloHello**<space>**HelloHelloHelloHello**<space>**HelloHelloHelloHell..(approx 60,000 characters with some space  in job description)  
 3       Job3         DemoDemoDemoDemo**<space>**DemoDemoDemoDemoDemo**<space>**DemoDemoDemo...(approx 60,000 characters with some space  in job description)  
 4       Job4         TestingTesting**<space>**TestingTestingTesting**<space>**TestingTesti....(approx 50,000 characters with some space  in job description)
```

So my question is, why select query takes too long time to execute when `jobdescription` don't have any space?
I think, time issue not related to amount of data in my case.

Comment: **Identical** query both times? You updated some data ran it again and it was faster? I can't explain why updating data would make that kind of difference. My guess is caching.

Comment: Interesting behavior.  Is it "deterministic"? Have you launched both queries repeatedly? If you really want to analyze it deeply you could produce a complete test scenario.  The risk is that the behavior could be related to how the data got in the table in first place,  and about how you made the "space addition" modification.

Comment: One scenario that comes to my mind is that the table originally was very fragmented.  To test it you might have done something (created a copy of the table?) that has created an unfragmented version of the table itself.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it might be a caching issue. In brief:

- Data is stored on the hard drive
- When a query comes in, SQL reads the data from the hard drive (disk) into memory, and then passes it back from memory to the user who requested it
- Reading data from disk is costly in terms of time
- To increase performance, any data read from disk to memory is left in memory “for a while”
- Done this way, subsequent queries that access the same data will find it in memory, and not have to read from disk again
- In SQL Server, this part of memory is referred to as the “buffer cache”
- There are extensive articles and discussions on how all this works both in Books Online (SQL Server documentation) and elsewhere.

So, my theory is:

- When you ran `Select * from TblJobs`, SQL loaded the relevant data from disk into memory
- When you updated the data, it first got updated in memory and then written back to disk… with the changed data remaining in memory
- When you ran `Select * from TblJobs` again, it read the data straight from memory.
- That first read was still extremely long. quite possibly, as @Insac said, the table is fragmented on the hard drive and required “extra” time to read.

To test this, use the command `DBCC DropCleanBuffers`. This will clear out the buffer cache, requiring all subsequent queries to read from disk. So:

- Run `DBCC DropCleanBuffers` to clear the buffers
- Run `Select * from TblJobs` to read the data straight from disk. Time how long it takes.
- Run `Select * from TblJobs` again, several times, timing each. These will be read from memory
- Run `DBCC DropCleanBuffers` to clear the buffers again
- Run `Select * from TblJobs` to read the data from disk again.
- Run `Select * from TblJobs` again, several times, timing each.

Much depends on how much data is being read and how much memory you have on the machine--but hey, memory gets pretty big these days, and I suspect this will not be an issue.

You can mix in runs of `Select JobId, JobTitle, JobDescription from TblJobs`. That returns the exact same set of data, and it should make no difference to your execution times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why it likes this, but a couple of thing you might want to try:

1. look at the execution plan to find clues
2. Replace the * with the actual column names - don't know why, but it sometimes helps
3. add index to each column and try (until you find the best one)
4. try to change the primary key's index type - try Clustered instead of Non-Clustered
5. try to create a view upon this table and query from the view instead

hope you could resolve it...

Answer (score 0):

Well selecting * from a table is always going to be fairly slow as you are asking the DBMS to scan the entire table for every row and return the results. If you want specific results and to optimize, I'd recommend you modify the queries to select the specific columns you want.
Eg.

```
select * from TblJobs.JobTitle, TblJobs.JobDescription
```

As for the space between your text in your job description resulting in a faster retrieval time, this is more of a guess but could it be due to the indexing nature specified by you or your DBMS when you set up the table? The extremely long continuous string might take longer to read or determine where to proceed to retrieve your data. That or the DBMS has caching mechanisms in place that may have made the second search considerably quicker after the first execution (See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html))

Hope this helps.

Comment: `select * from TblJobs.JobTitle, TblJobs.JobDescription` - syntax is not correct, I already try this - `select TblJobs.JobTitle, TblJobs.JobDescription from  TblJobs`. but it's take almost same time to execute.

Comment: Oh wow, my apologies silly mistake on my part. That's what I get for writing it on a phone, It would have only been a small optimization as it would have been one less column but you still scanned all the rows. I'll do a bit more research and get back to you, it's an interesting question.